# ordered associative data structure optimised for fast lookup?

Tags: c++, stl

I'm looking for a `std::map`-esque data structure optimised for **fast lookup**.

One approach would be to implement map's interface utilising a sorted `std::vector` as the underlying storage - this will offer fast `binary_search` thanks to random-access iterators and cache locality.

However, this sounds like reinvention of the wheel. Surely something like this already exists?

Is there an open-source ordered associative data structure which uses a std::vector for storage?

**Edit:**

In response to the comments suggesting *just use std::map* - please read here: http://lafstern.org/matt/col1.pdf

Comment: A map *has* fast lookup. How much faster do you want it to be?!

Comment: You might be looking for Boost's "flat map", from Boost.Containers.

Comment: What's wrong with `std::map`? It is extremely `std::map`-esque, and is optimised for fat lookup.

Comment: @JesseGood: `unordered_map` is strangely enough not an *ordered* associative data structure... go figure. :P

Comment: As Kerrek suggests, you might want to check out [boost::flat_map](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/container/non_standard_containers.html#container.non_standard_containers.flat_xxx).

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: Thanks :). I should read questions more carefully.

Comment: @KerrekSB - thanks - flat-map is exactly what I was looking for - make is an answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Boost.Containers library has an ordered map container whose storage is backed by a contiguous array called [`boost::flat_map`](http://www.boost.org/doc/html/container/non_standard_containers.html#container.non_standard_containers.flat_xxx). Note however that the asymptotic, theoretic complexity is the same as for the standard `map` (logarithmic), and the choice which is better depends on many *details* of the use case: insertions vs. lookups, iterations, iterator invalidation requirements.

Since the interfaces are very similar, it should be possible to literally replace one by the other via a typedef and profile the relative performances, which is something you absolutely must do.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there an open-source ordered associative data structure which uses
>   a std::vector for storage?

How about maintaining a **sorted `vector`**? That way look-up can be fast (binary search, without pointer traversal).